How to access Umbraco Web Models Link
So I'm rebuilding an old website that was originally on Umbraco 7, and putting it onto Umbraco 8 (Yes I know it's also nearing EOL, this is just for security measures)
The problem I'm having is building the navigation menu.
I can get it to pull the correct names for the links, but the URL's are wrong.
The code below shows how I'm getting the menu names and links, names are fine. But from my understanding the link is stored in a different member, and the one stored in menuItem.URL() isn't the one I want.
@foreach (var menuItem in root.MenuLink.Children())
  {
      var menuItemHasChildren = menuItem.Children.Any();
      <li class="nav-level-1__item">
          <a href="@menuItem.Url()" class="nav-level-1__link" data-tsat="nav-menu_item" data-nav-title="@menuItem.Name" target="@menuItem.Url()">
              @menuItem.Name
          </a>`

From my understanding there's a way to strongly type links in Umbraco but I'm not 100% sure how to do it.
I can find the correct link I want to use by doing the following:
Put my code into debug mode, and put a breakpoint in var menuItemHasChildren = menuItem.Children.Any();
Then when I hover over menuItem it brings up a list on members, in that list there's one called 'Link' and inside there I can click [0], then that brings up another members list and inside there is 'url' which has the correct url.
The problem is I can't just type menuItem.Link because it says Link doesn't exist.
Here's an image showing where I'm trying to get:

How can I access the Link member inside menuItem.
I've tried different ways of accessing the Link member of MenuItem but nothing has led me anywhere.
I tried using this code but I just get a null error:
var umbracoLink = menuLink.Value<Umbraco.Web.Models.Link>("menuItem");

  if (umbracoLink != null)
  {
      // Accessing the URL property of the Umbraco.Web.Models.Link object
      var url = umbracoLink.Url;

      <li class="nav-level-1__item">
          <a href="@url" class="nav-level-1__link" data-tsat="nav-menu_item" data-nav-title="@menuItem.Name" target="@url">
              @menuItem.Name
          </a>


Do you generate strongly-typed published content models for your Umbraco v7 project by using something like Zbu.ModelsBuilder?
You should have ModelsBuilder out-of-the box in your v8 project, as this package was later moved into the Umbraco CMS core code. I'd recommend you use it to generate your models, and then you can cast your object to your strongly typed model and reach the necessary properties as you wish.
Here is an example of how you can do it; also see a similar question answered on Umbraco Forum below:
private static List<fields.Image> GetImageGalleryElementImages(IEnumerable<IPublishedContent> images)
{
    var elementImages = new List<fields.Image>();

    if (images != null && images.Any())
    {
        foreach (var item in images)
        {
            if (item is Image)
            {
                // CASTING: Cast item to ModelsBuilder model and reach its properties afterwards
                var modelsBuilderValue = item as Image;

                elementImages.Add(new fields.Image()
                {
                    Url = modelsBuilderValue.Url,// todo: obsolete
                    Alt = modelsBuilderValue.Alt
                });
            }
        }
    }

    return elementImages;
}

https://our.umbraco.com/forum/using-umbraco-and-getting-started/103099-rendering-links-to-view-in-umbraco-8#comment-322214

